# SQLite Full-Text Search with PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, full-text-search

I created the sqlite-FTS4 table with multiple columns such as:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE [selection_fts] USING fts4 (tender_id, tender_orderName_clean, tender_fm, branch, lot_name_clean);
```

and I try to execute code like

```
$q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM selection_fts WHERE selection_fts MATCH (\"(tender_orderName_clean:двер* OR lot_name_clean:двер*) AND tender_fm:Министерство Иностранных Дел AND branch:на строительство\") limit 0,250");
$rows = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($rows);
die();
```

The code above returns 0 rows, but in my SQlite manager I see some results.
Do you please explain my mistake?

Comment: this code will result in a mere syntax error

Comment: Corrected the typo here, thanks. But I still have no results.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is an old question, I just ran into the same issue and found out that (atleast in my case) the exact MATCH to the database entry didn't return any results. When I took irrelevant parts out of the MATCH string, I got results back.

Might be a bug in the SQLite driver, maybe...